# Why is my strategy.close triggering a buy/sell alert?

Tags: binary, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I have a {{strategy.order.action}} alert message set up that automates my trades. However recently, since the new trading view update. I've been receiving alert messages that triggers a buy/sell action for my strategy.close.

```
//Short Conditions
if (ShortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Long Conditions 

if (LongCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Close the position after 4 bars
if barsSinceLastEntry() >= 4
    strategy.close("Long")
    strategy.close("Short")
```

any help on why trading view is reading the strategy.close and putting in another trade order for me after 4 bars instead of just "closing" the trade (which I use the statistics for backtesting)

I've tried to create different alerts or change the syntax of the script. It is still triggering a buy/sell after 4 minutes instead of closing the trade.

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand the behavior you described exactly BUT, I can think of 2 possible solutions:

1- check if your `barsSinceLastEntry()` is working correctly. You may use `labels` for debugging.

2- close longs and shorts separately and check if there is a position before that.

Comment: barsSinceLastEntry is working correctly. I'm having this same problem on all my scripts (even simple ones). Creating the alert through trading view reads my if statement correctly to put in a long or short trade. However, closing the trade does the opposite action.

Comment: For example: sell trade will trigger and after 4 minutes, the alert will trigger a buy. "closing" the trade. However, I just use the strategy.close for statistics. I don't want it to trigger an actual trade. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @HakunaMatia then check the second solution

Comment: @HakunaMatia it is also possible that both the entry and exit logics are met at the same candle, you can try putting the exit logic before the entry

Comment: unfortunately it is still triggering the alert for the strategy.close

Answer (score 0):

Closing a short position is a long order vica versa. You can use the comment argument to make it clear what the script does. For example:

```
strategy.entry("Open looong #1337", strategy.long)

strategy.close("Open looong #1337", "This is a short order which close the Open looong #1337 position")
```